# On writing image to Excel File in JAVA, I am receiving - java.awt.image.DataBufferInt cannot be cast to java.awt.image.DataBufferByte

Tags: java, eclipse

I am fairly new to JAVA and got stuck with this problem while exporting images to excel file in ECLIPSE. I am not sure what and how to do, would be great, if someone could assist:

```
                ImageIcon[][] icons = getIconList() ;

                for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
                    ImageIcon[] iconsRow = icons[i];

                    for (int j = 0; j < iconsRow.length; j++) {
                        ImageIcon icon = iconsRow[j];
                        BufferedImage bufferedImage = (BufferedImage) icon.getImage();


                        DataBufferByte bufferdData  = (DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
                        byte[] imagesBytes = bufferdData.getData();
                        int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(imagesBytes , Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
                        HSSFPicture pic = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
```

Comment: Its because DataBufferInt which is returned from getDataBuffer() can not be casted to DataBufferByte. As DataBufferByte is not a subclass of DataBufferInt. Both extend DataBuffer but they are not extending each other

Comment: Thanks saurav, appreciate the response. If possible, could you please guide me with a correct solution for the same since I am fairly new to this stuff and having trouble with logically understanding.